# Частичная специализация шаблоном класса C++

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++

Появилась достаточно неоднозначная задача. Есть абстрактный модуль "Фильтр":

```
template <typename T, typename DelayLineType>
class FilterAbstract
{
public:
    explicit FilterAbstract(uint32_t length);
    explicit FilterAbstract(const FilterAbstract &object);
    FilterAbstract &operator=(const FilterAbstract &object);
    virtual ~FilterAbstract() = default;

    virtual T Step(const T &value) = 0;

    DelayLineType DelayLine;
    Vector<T> Coefficients;
};
```

Далее я наследую абстрактный класс с частичной специализацией:

```
template <typename T>
class FilterOnCircularVectors : public FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<T>>
{
public:
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors(uint32_t length);
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors(const FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<T>> &object);

    T Step(const T &value) override;

};
```

Теперь я помимо такого наследования хочу обеспечить частичную специализацию путем использования класса `Complex<T>` и тут появляется недопонимание как это реализовать правильно с одним и тем же именем в том же файле:

```
template <template T>
class FilterOnCircularVectors : public FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<Complex<T>>>
{
public:
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors(uint32_t length);
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors(const FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<Complex<T>>> &object);

    Complex<T> Step(const Complex<T> &value) override;

};
```

Есть какие-то мысли на этот счет? Плодить классы с пометкой Complex не очень хочется.

**UPD:**
В VS2019 если создать два класса с такими именами и таким наследованием, то возникает ошибка из-за множественного определения.
Дело в том, что разное поведение должно быть у функции `Step` при `CircularVector<T>` и `CircularVector<Complex<T>>`

Comment: Жаль, что у вас нет минимального компилируемого кода, чтоб не писать наобум, а попробовать сначала самому... Но если попробовать `template <typename T>
class FilterOnCircularVectors : public FilterAbstract<Complex<T>, CircularVector<Complex<T>>>` - что говорит?

Comment: Код компилируется если имена разные у классов. С одинаковыми именами не получается сделать перегрузку. Почему?

Comment: Эмм... Если потом в коде создать `FilterOnCircularVectors<int> obj;`, то какой шаблон класса будет использоваться?

Comment: Т.е. `FilterOnCircularVectors<int> obj(static_cast<uint32_t>(10));` Не обратил внимание на конструкторы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как заметил @AR Hovsepyan задача решается, но дополнительно необходимо соблюсти правила наследования абстрактной функции. Тогда решение будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
template <typename T>
class FilterOnCircularVectors<Complex<T>>
    : public FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<Complex<T>>>
{
public:
    /*Если классу нужны свои конструкторы, то нужно
    в списке инициализации конструктора инициализировать
    и базовый объект(он кажется даже не конструируется по
     умолчанию)*/

    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors<Complex<T>>(uint32_t length);
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors<Complex<T>>(const FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<Complex<T>>> &object);
    Complex<T> Step(const Complex<T> &value);
private:
    T Step(const T &value) override;
};
```

Это связано с тем, что абстрактная функция наследуется с параметром `T` а для решения моей задачи требуется `Complex<T>`

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужно отделять шаблон от специализации. Если даже специализация частичная, то должна определяться именно эта специализация, а вы тот же шаблон пытаетесь переопределять. А нужно определять `FilterOnCircularVectors< Complex<T> >`, следующим образом:

```
template <typename T>
class FilterOnCircularVectors<Complex<T>> 
      : public FilterAbstract<T, CircularVector<Complex<T>>>
{
public:
    /*Если классу нужны свои конструкторы, то нужно
    в списке инициализации конструктора инициализировать
    и базовый объект(он кажется даже не конструируется по 
     умолчанию)*/

    Complex<T> Step(const Complex<T>& value) override;

};
```

Comment: @OnuchinVA, ваша попытка правки абсолютно  непонятна. Вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: попробуйте скомпилировать код. У меня под VS2019 не работает. С теми правками, что я внес в ваш ответ - заработало бы.

Comment: Ну, скажем, мне не нужно пробовать. Только я не понимаю как вы сами пробуете. Не нужно пытаться поправлять то, что написал человек, ясно знающий тему, тем более, что вы сами только изучаете. Лучше просто спросить  не ошибается ли он или согласен он с вашим мнением?  Если вам интересно,задавайте отдельный вопрос и получите ответ. Квалификатор доступа никак не влияет ни на что при переопределении. Он только разрешает или запрещает доступ.

Answer (score 0):

В последнем примере вы изменяете возвращаемый и принимаемый тип.
В базовом классе у вас инстанцируется

```
virtual T Step(const T &value) = 0;
```

А вы хотите

```
virtual Complex<T> Step(const Complex<T> &value) = 0;
```

Для того, чтобы было последнее вы должны подавать первым аргументом в шаблон не T, а `Complex<T>`, тогда всё должно работать

```
template <typename T>
class FilterOnCircularVectors : public FilterAbstract<Complex<T>, CircularVector<Complex<T>>>
{
public:
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors(uint32_t length);
    explicit FilterOnCircularVectors(const FilterAbstract<Complex<T>, CircularVector<Complex<T>>> &object);

    Complex<T> Step(const Complex<T> &value) override;

};
```

Заранее предупреждаю, что в данном случае вы не сможете воспользоваться полиморфизмом при подаче разных типов.

Если же вы хотите именно частичную специализацию, то нужно сделать так

```
template <typename T, typename DelayLineType>
class FilterAbstract<Complex<T>, DelayLineType>
{
public:
    explicit FilterAbstract(uint32_t length);
    explicit FilterAbstract(const FilterAbstract &object);
    FilterAbstract &operator=(const FilterAbstract &object);
    virtual ~FilterAbstract() = default;

    virtual Complex<T> Step(const Complex<T> &value) = 0;

    DelayLineType DelayLine;
    Vector<T> Coefficients;
};
```

Comment: тут вы сами запутались в ошибках...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Я так до конца и не понял, что хочет автор, и почему он назвал подачу обёрточного типа в шаблон частичной специализацией. Но этот код должен работать, все типы совпадают

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Вы можете сами убедиться [код](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9qdv78)

Comment: а что тут смотреть? Вы определяете один шаблон, который совершенно не нужен. ТС нужен совершенно другой шаблон и  его специализация. Вы уверены, что вопрос внимательно прочитали?

Comment: @КириллЧуркин я не хочу плодить классы с именами FilterComplex, хотелось бы чтобы универсально использовался класс Filter под числа Real и под числа Complex